# How to fill out information automatically in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index page which displays the information for two seminars. Each seminar has its own unique reference number as shown in the code below. When the user clicks the apply now button in a specific section, it redirects the user to the registration page. However, I want the Reference number on that page to be automatically filled out based on the button the user clicked. For example this is my index page:

```
<section class="sec">
<p class= "prt"> 1. PRT Seminar </p>
<p> Reference number: S00001 </p>
<a href="register.php">
<button id="button1">Apply Now</button>
</a>
</section>
<section class="sec">
<p class="prt"> 2. Developing a Written Diversity Statement Seminar</p>
<p> Reference number: S00002 </p>
<a href="register.php">
<button id="button2">Apply Now</button>
</a>
</section>
```

This is my registration page

```
 <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="process.php" novalidate="novalidate">
 <h1> User Registration Form </h1>
 <fieldset class="info">
<p><label for ="reference"> Seminar reference number: </label>
<input type="text" name="reference" id="reference" maxlength="10" size="10" required="required"/>
</p> 
</fieldset>
</form>
```

So, if the user clicks on the apply now button under PRT Seminar, the registration page should have S00001 filled out next to seminar reference number. How can I do that using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your users to the registration page and and pass in a query string into the url. So your registration page url could look like `https://myapp.com/registration-page?seminar=S00001`.

Then you can parse the query string on the registration page and render the `seminar` value inside of your HTML where you need it. You can write your own Javascript logic to do this or you can use an npm package like [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) to help you out.

Just make sure that you're only including the parsed values into your HTML in a safe way. So don't use `innerHTML`, etc. to render the value.You can read [this article](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) from OWASP on how to avoid common security mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference number as a parameter in the register link and then on the registration page you can take that parameter and put it in the input.

This is how you can pass it in the link

This is how to take params from url with javasrcipt
https://gomakethings.com/getting-all-query-string-values-from-a-url-with-vanilla-js/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add an event listener to the button  and then just get the place you want to fill in and change it's value.

Comment: element1.addEventListener("click",() => { // element1 is button on which you want to add event  
  element2.value = "text"; // element2 is element which's value we want to change
})